# Kill the reading tag

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [reading](/questions/tagged/reading) tag currently has 492 questions.

Arbitrarily checking 15 of those revealed that the tag doesn't really add anything; it's far too general and applies to many languages and situations.

Could we please?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxOCc.gif]

Comment: "Arbiterarily": In the manner of an arbiter?

Comment: What other way can your arbitrate whether the tag deserves to exist @Daniel :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Oh, I'm entirely in support of good arbitration. I just haven't known that word yet, so I wanted to ascertain that I understood it correctly.

Comment: Ah, no in that case @daniel. I believe Madara meant [arbitrarily](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/arbitrarily), which means "on a whim".

Comment: Yeah, thanks @benisuǝqbackwards.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Pity! A good neologism it would have been.

Comment: And the [books] tag, [ebooks] tag, [articles], [tutorials], [online-resources], [omgwtf], [etc]

Comment: http://s12.postimg.org/48c0lr625/Capture.png